# How do I effectively use a 'wire' key cap puller?

Tags: keyboard

I've used a 'ring' style key puller for years to remove keys from mechanical keyboards for cleaning or replacement. I've used it with a fairly enclosed black widow ultimate with no issues

[image]

It neatly fits over a key in one dimension - even the wider ones, and you just yank it it.

[image]

My new keyboard [Its a drop ctrl - and I believe its the 'default' one drop ships] comes with one that vaguely looks like a small whisk - and I seem to have to hook it over smaller keys at a 45 degree angle, and struggle with larger keys like shift keys and spacebars. Even where the keys have some clearance under them, it is significantly more finicky.

[image]

I think this kinda shows the problem best.

I feel like I'm missing something - its supposed to be 'easier' but when I was removing keycaps off a keyboard, I found the ring style much faster and simpler
since it just hooked in and pulled.

I guess in theory the whisk is more flexible but the width of keys seems standard, and clip and pull seems faster than 'put wire whisk just right, let it spread and twist to hook'   .

How *do* I use a wire key cap puller properly ?

Answer (score 3):

Wire keycap pullers are regarded as better than ring keycap pullers because those are known to scratch the paint off of keycaps, especially ABS keycaps. Looks like this: [image]

When I want to remove the spacebar I use one keycap puller on each side and very gently pull up. Then I pull one end of the stabilizer out of the spacebar and then the other one.

Comment: I guess it makes sense with the closer fit, but needing a second keypuller for bigger keys seems.... annoying.  It seems a little counterintuitive that metal is 'gentler' than plastic to me ._.

Comment: The Problem with the plastic ring puller is that when you slide it down to the bottom of the keycap you can scratch the paint off. The fact that the thin wires slide in from the side makes it safer

Comment: I put a link in my original answer so you can see what these scratches look like.

Comment: I've never seen that, and I've used the ring style for the better part of a decade. I'm  also still not sure if I'm using the wire style 'correctly'